# LINQ nested list comprehension to get files from several folders

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get `.mp3` files from multiple folders.

I can already do it for one folder through this query :

```
this.MusicList.ItemsSource =
                from string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music")
                where System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".mp3"
                select new FileInfo(fileName);
```

Is there any other way to do it for a list of directories ?

Here is what I have tried so far (returns no results):

```
var paths = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            {"default_music", @"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music"},
            {"alternative_folder", @"C:\tmp"}
            };

this.MusicList.ItemsSource = 
from string fileName in (from string directoryName in paths.Values select Directory.GetFiles(directoryName))
where System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".mp3"
select new FileInfo(fileName);
```

`from string directoryName in paths.Values select Directory.GetFiles(directoryName);` returns a `{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<string,string[]>}` with my paths in its `source` field and its `Result View` contains of my `.mp3` files.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following

```
this.MusicList.ItemsSource =
  from path in paths
  from fileName in Directory.GetFiles(path)
  where System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".mp3"
  select new FileInfo(fileName);
```

Strict method call version

```
this.MusicList.ItemSource = paths
  .SelectMany(path => Directory.GetFiles(path))
  .Where(fileName => System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".mp3")
  .Select(fileName => new FileInfo(fileName));
```

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles` has an overload with takes a `searchPattern` which you should use to filter:

    `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music", "*.mp3");`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574.aspx) method which accepts **search pattern**. Thus you don't need to get all files and filter them via calls to `Path.GetExtension`

```
var paths = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"default_music", @"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music"},
        {"alternative_folder", @"C:\tmp"}
     };

MusicList.ItemsSource = paths.Values.Select(p => new DirectoryInfo(p))
                             .SelectMany(d => d.EnumerateFiles("*.mp3"));
```

Also `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` returns `FileInfo` instances, which is also what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music", "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

to return an enumerable list of .mp3's, which you can further filter or enumerate etc.  This is more efficient than `GetFiles()` for large numbers of files and/or directories.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to the esteemable JaredPar that tracks if it's a File/Directory:

```
var basePath = @"c:\temp";
var query = 
    from entry in Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(basePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    let isDirectory = Directory.Exists(entry)
    let isFile = File.Exists(entry)
    select new { isDirectory, isFile, entry};
query.Dump();
```

EDIT: Doh - misread question, missed the "from a set of directories" part; my shame is immeasurable. :)

Comment: paths will be returned from a `FolderBrowserDialog` so I don't need to check this. Thank you for your input though.